# Pie Chart slices in swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I'm trying to make a pie chart. Actually it's done, but I would like to get some values, and each value should be a slice of the pie. The only thing I could do is fill the pie with a slider. How can I make different slices with different colors for some values?

Here is my code for drawing the chart (I got here in stack) :

```
   import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ChartView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var progress : Double =  0.0 {

        didSet {
                self.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }


    @IBInspectable var noProgress : Double =  0.0 {

        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }


        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder:aDecoder)
            self.contentMode = .Redraw
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.contentMode = .Redraw
        }

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            let color = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            let lineWidth : CGFloat = 2.0

            // Calculate box with insets
            let margin: CGFloat = lineWidth
            let box0 = CGRectInset(self.bounds, margin, margin)
            let side : CGFloat = min(box0.width, box0.height)
            let box = CGRectMake((self.bounds.width-side)/2, (self.bounds.height-side)/2,side,side)


            let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            // Draw outline
            CGContextBeginPath(ctx)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth)
            CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, box)
            CGContextClosePath(ctx)
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx)

            // Draw arc
            let delta : CGFloat = -CGFloat(M_PI_2)
            let radius : CGFloat = min(box.width, box.height)/2.0

            func prog_to_rad(p: Double) -> CGFloat {
                let rad = CGFloat((p *  M_PI)/180)
                return rad
            }

            func draw_arc(s: CGFloat, e: CGFloat, color: CGColor) {
                CGContextBeginPath(ctx)
                CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, box.midX, box.midY)
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color)

                CGContextAddArc(ctx, box.midX, box.midY, radius-lineWidth/2, s, e, 0)

                CGContextClosePath(ctx)
                CGContextFillPath(ctx)
            }


            if progress > 0 {
                let s = prog_to_rad(noProgress * 360/100)
                let e = prog_to_rad(progress * 360/100)
                draw_arc(s, e, color)
            }


    }
}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: ChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func setValue(sender: UISlider) {

    pieChartView.progress = Double(sender.value)



    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is from my [blogpost](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/swift-going-round-in-semicircles-with.html), it uses CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath. You can create any number of segments with whichever choice of colour you like.

```
extension CGFloat {
    func radians() -> CGFloat {
        let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * (self/180)
        return b
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    convenience init(circleSegmentCenter center:CGPoint, radius:CGFloat, startAngle:CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat)
    {
        self.init()
        self.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(center.x, center.y))
        self.addArcWithCenter(center, radius:radius, startAngle:startAngle.radians(), endAngle: endAngle.radians(), clockwise:true)
        self.closePath()
    }
}



func pieChart(pieces:[(UIBezierPath, UIColor)], viewRect:CGRect) -> UIView {
    var layers = [CAShapeLayer]()
    for p in pieces {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = p.0.CGPath
        layer.fillColor = p.1.CGColor
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layers.append(layer)
    }
    let view = UIView(frame: viewRect)
    for l in layers {

        view.layer.addSublayer(l)


    }
    return view
}

let rectSize = CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)
let centrePointOfChart = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectSize),CGRectGetMidY(rectSize))
let radius:CGFloat = 100
let piePieces = [(UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 250, endAngle: 360),UIColor.brownColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 200),UIColor.orangeColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 200, endAngle: 250),UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
pieChart(piePieces, viewRect: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using this code and it works great to draw my pie-chart.  But I've spent the last 4 hours trying to add text (eg "24%") to the individual slices and can't get any text to show up at all....and certainly not centered on the slice.  When I print the layer.bounds, they all show to be 0,0,0,0 so I'm guessing that is clipping my text somehow.  But I can see the slices because clipToBounds defaults to false so that doesn't make sense..... all tips appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Dewey, I've written a rough [gist](https://gist.github.com/sketchytech/d077388a09ff4455be5d64747374155a) to give you a way of adding text labels with positioning based on this [equation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17427257/1694526). From here you should be able to write code to create an array of labels and apply them in a cleaner way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You posted a bunch of code that appears to draw a single pie chart "slice" in a single color.

Are you saying that you don't know how to make it draw an entire pie, with slices of different sizes, and that you don't know how to make each slice a different color?

It sounds to me like you are copy/pasting code you got from somewhere and have no idea how it works. How about you walk us through what your code does and give us a clearer idea of where you're stuck?

We're not here to take your copy/paste code and modify it for you to make it meet your requirements. Sounds like custom development to me. I don't know about the other posters on this board, but I get paid for that.

As it happens I've written a development blog post that includes a sample app that generates pie charts in Swift. You can see it here:

http://wareto.com/swift-piecharts

Instead of overriding drawRect like the code you posted, it creates a CAShapeLayer that holds the pie chart. It manages a pie chart with a variable number of "slices", and will either change the arc of each slice, the radius, or both.

It is not set up to make each slice a different color. For that you'd have to modify it to use separate shape layers for each slice, which would be a fairly big structural change to the program.

It does at least show you how to draw a pie chart in Swift for iOS:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i will try to make, and I will try to understand. I have a big difficulty in the draw stuff. Do you have any material to me for understand the draw stuff? Or a tutorial? Thanks again...

Comment: I posted a link to a blog post that includes the source for a working application. That should be everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is useful for Pie Chart Slice space in swift. Check out once

import UIKit

private extension CGFloat {

```
/// Formats the CGFloat to a maximum of 1 decimal place.
var formattedToOneDecimalPlace : String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.native)) ?? "\(self)"
}
```

}

/// Defines a segment of the pie chart

struct Segment {

```
/// The color of the segment
var color : UIColor

/// The name of the segment
var name : String

/// The value of the segment
var value : CGFloat
```

}

class PieChartView: UIView {

```
/// An array of structs representing the segments of the pie chart
var segments = [Segment]() {
    didSet {
        totalValue = segments.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
        setupLabels()
        setNeedsDisplay() // re-draw view when the values get set
        layoutLabels();
    } // re-draw view when the values get set
}

/// Defines whether the segment labels should be shown when drawing the pie chart
var showSegmentLabels = true {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

/// Defines whether the segment labels will show the value of the segment in brackets
var showSegmentValueInLabel = false {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

/// The font to be used on the segment labels
var segmentLabelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14) {
    didSet {
        textAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = segmentLabelFont
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

private let paragraphStyle : NSParagraphStyle = {
    var p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    p.alignment = .center
    return p.copy() as! NSParagraphStyle
}()

private lazy var textAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject] = {
    return [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : self.paragraphStyle, NSAttributedStringKey.font : self.segmentLabelFont]
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    isOpaque = false // when overriding drawRect, you must specify this to maintain transparency.
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

private var labels: [UILabel] = []
private var totalValue: CGFloat = 1;

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let anglePI2 = (CGFloat.pi * 2)
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.5;

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ctx?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)


    var currentAngle: CGFloat = 0

    if totalValue <= 0 {
        totalValue = 1
    }

    let iRange = 0 ..< segments.count
    for i in iRange {
        let segment = segments[i]
        // calculate percent
        let percent = segment.value / totalValue

        let angle = anglePI2 * percent

        ctx?.beginPath()
        ctx?.move(to: center)
        ctx?.addArc(center: center, radius: radius - lineWidth, startAngle: currentAngle, endAngle: currentAngle + angle, clockwise: false)
        ctx?.closePath()

        ctx?.setFillColor(segment.color.cgColor)
        ctx?.fillPath()

        ctx?.beginPath()
        ctx?.move(to: center)
        ctx?.addArc(center: center, radius: radius - (lineWidth / 2), startAngle: currentAngle, endAngle: currentAngle + angle, clockwise: false)
        ctx?.closePath()

        ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        ctx?.strokePath()

        currentAngle += angle
    }


}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layoutLabels()
}
private func setupLabels() {
    var diff = segments.count - labels.count;
    if diff >= 0 {
        for _ in 0 ..< diff {
            let lbl = UILabel()
            self.addSubview(lbl)
            labels.append(lbl)
        }
    } else {

            while diff != 0 {
                var lbl: UILabel!
                if labels.count <= 0 {
                    break;
                }
                lbl = labels.removeLast()
                if lbl.superview != nil {
                    lbl.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                diff += 1;
            }

    }

    for i in 0 ..< segments.count {
        let lbl = labels[i]
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        // Change here for your text display
        // I currently display percent of each pies
        lbl.text = "\(segments[i].value.formattedToOneDecimalPlace)%" //String.init(format: "%0.0f", segments[i].value)
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    }
}
func layoutLabels() {
    let anglePI2 = CGFloat.pi * 2
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width / 2, bounds.size.height / 2) / 1.5

    var currentAngle: CGFloat = 0;
    let iRange = 0 ..< labels.count
    for i in iRange {
        let lbl = labels[i]
        let percent = segments[i].value / totalValue

        let intervalAngle = anglePI2 * percent;
        lbl.frame = .zero;
        lbl.sizeToFit()

        let x = center.x + radius * cos(currentAngle + (intervalAngle / 2))
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(currentAngle + (intervalAngle / 2))
        lbl.center = CGPoint.init(x: x, y: y)


        currentAngle += intervalAngle

    }
}
```

}