# Rotate every arc of pie chart 180 (like sun) with D3 JS. How to calculate translate parameters

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am working on pie chart with d3 js. I want to rotate every arc of my pie chart 180. I know that I am unable to explain completely show here is my fiddle link.

```
[fiddle]: https://jsfiddle.net/dsLonquL/
```

How can i get dynamic parameters for translate() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to work out the centre point of the edge of each arc. I used this example for help : [How to get coordinates of slices along the edge of a pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427088/how-to-get-coordinates-of-slices-along-the-edge-of-a-pie-chart)

This works okay, but I needed to rotate the points to get them in the correct positions. As it is in radians the rotation is the following :

```
 var rotationInRadians = 1.5708 * 1.5;
```

Now using the example before I used the data for the paths, so the start and end angle and got the center points like so :

```
var thisAngle = (d.startAngle + rotationInRadians + (d.endAngle + rotationInRadians - d.startAngle + rotationInRadians) / 2);
    var x = centreOfPie[0] + radius * 2 * Math.cos(thisAngle)
    var y = centreOfPie[1] + radius * 2 * Math.sin(thisAngle)
```

I created a function to show circles at these points to clarify :

```
function drawCircle(points, colour) {
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', points[0])
      .attr('cy', points[1])
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('fill', colour);

  }
```

Called it inside the current function like so :

```
drawCircle([x, y], color(d.data.label))
```

And then translated and rotated accordingly :

```
return 'translate(' + (x) + ',' + y + ') rotate(180)';
```

I added a transition so you can see it working. Here is the final fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/dsLonquL/7/

EDIT

In your comments you say you want the biggest segment to be kept in the middle. So we need to run through the segments and get the biggest. I have also taken care of duplicates, i.e if two or more segments are the same size.

Here is the added code :

```
 var biggestSegment = {
    angle: 0,
    index: []
  };

 path.each(function(d, i) {
    var thisAngle = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle).toFixed(6);//i had to round them as the numbers after around the 7th or 8th decimal point tend to differ tet theyre suppose to be the same value
    if (i == 0) {
      biggestSegment.angle = thisAngle
    } else {
      if (biggestSegment.angle < thisAngle) {
        biggestSegment.angle = thisAngle;
        biggestSegment.index = [i];
      } else if (biggestSegment.angle == thisAngle) {
      console.log('push')
        biggestSegment.index.push(i);
      }
    }
  })
```

Now this goes through each path checks if its bigger than the current value, if it is overwrite the biggest value and make note of the index. If its the same, add index to index array.

Now when translating the paths, you need to check the current index against the index array above to see if it needs rotating. Like so :

```
 if (biggestSegment.index.indexOf(i) > -1) {
      return 'translate(' + (centreOfPie[0]) + ',' + (centreOfPie[1]) + ')' // rotate(180)';
    } else {
      return 'translate(' + (x) + ',' + y + ') rotate(180)';
    }
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/dsLonquL/8/

I have editted 3 values to be different to the rest. Go ahead and change these, see what you think :)

Comment: If these are not in the corrent positions just edit the first value when setting x and y. So at the moment its centerOfPie[n], where centerOfPie is, you guessed it, the center of the pie.

Comment: Thanks @thatOneGuy, You give me hope that I can be done.It is too close to my need. I am working on it. The problem is that if there are different slices with different sizes than how to manage it. It is going here and there but we need that chart have nearby near slices.

Comment: Im not sure i understand the problem. The code I have put together should cater for segments of different sizes. Whats wrong with your side ?

Comment: If I change one dataset value of count with the huge margin with other than that slice go far from other slices. try this dataset    
             {
                    label: 'green',
                    count: 200
                },

Comment: what would you expect it to look like if you had a huge value there ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @thatOneGuy. Slices can have different size and slice which have the greatest value will have direction inside.You can see here [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/anshulkumar/yh3v3hx5/)

Comment: @Anshul no problem, would help show people its been solved by hitting the tick next the the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure middle school geometry job.

**CASE 1: The vertex of each sector rotation is on the outer line of the circle**

[image: The vertex on the edge]

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13j5avmo/1/)

```
// ... previous code there
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return color(d.data.label);
      })
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var a = (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2, // angle of vertex
        dx = 2 * radius * Math.sin(a),       // shift/translate  is two times of the vertex coordinate
        dy = - 2 * radius * Math.cos(a);     // the same
        return ("translate(" + dx + " " + dy + ") rotate(180)"); // output
      });
```

**CASE 2: The vertex on the center of the chord**

[image: The vertex on the center of the chord]

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk1kua3b/2/)

```
// ... previous code there
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return color(d.data.label);
      })
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var dx = radius * (Math.sin(d.endAngle) + Math.sin(d.startAngle)), // shift/translation as coordinate of vertex
        dy = - radius * (Math.cos(d.endAngle) + Math.cos(d.startAngle)); // the same for Y
        return ("translate(" + dx + " " + dy + ") rotate(180)"); // output
      });
```

Comment: thanks @Ruben Kazumov everything is perfect but if I change the data then the structure is not fit.        [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/anshulkumar/mk1kua3b/3/)